Is there a way I can determine start position of an animation in chart.js using a websocket datasource?
I have implemented an area chart in my angular application using chart.js (ng2-charts). Data is populated on the chart using a WebSocket. However, when animating the inserted data point, the curve starts from the bottom and then goes up to the actual value. I however would like the animation to start from the previous data point if not closer.
This is where i'm initialising the data and a sample of how i'm populating it
  public lineChartData: ChartConfiguration<'line'>['data'] = {
    labels: [],
    datasets: [
      {
        data: [],
        fill: true,
        tension: 0.5,
        borderColor: '#fdec0a',
        backgroundColor: '#555318',
        pointStyle: 'line',
      },
    ],
  };
  public lineChartOptions: ChartOptions<'line'> = {
    responsive: true,
    scales: {
      x: {
        display: false,
      },
      y: {
        display: true,
      },
    },
    animations: {},
  };

 setInterval(() => {
      this.lastValue += Math.random() * 10;
      this.lineChartData.labels.push('');
      this.lineChartData.datasets[0].data.push(this.lastValue);
      this.lineChartOptions.animations.y = {
        from: this.lastValue*10,
        to: this.lastValue,
      };
      this.lineChartOptions.animations.x = {
        from: this.lastValue*10,
        to: this.lastValue,
      };
      this.chart?.update();
      console.log(this.lastValue, 'this.lastValue');
    }, 2000);

